# IBM Watson: Stream closed exception while recursively adding documents to the collection

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I have Discovery instance in my IBM Bluemix account and I want to add documents from a local folder to a private collection in this Discovery instance. I do it by basically calling a recursive function from the main local folder. The procedure itself works fine; however, after a few iterations of adding documents I encounteer the following error:

```
Aug 08, 2017 1:55:07 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environmentId}/collections/{collectionId}/documents?version=2017-08-01 http/1.1 (-1-byte body)
Aug 08, 2017 1:59:09 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Aug 08, 2017 1:59:10 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environmentId}/collections/{collectionId}/documents?version=2017-08-01 http/1.1 (-1-byte body)
Aug 08, 2017 1:59:10 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
```

How I do is that I first initialize a Discovery instance:

```
Discovery discovery = new Discovery("2017-08-01");
discovery.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api");
discovery.setUsernameAndPassword({username}, {password});
```

Then for each mime-supported file *f* of file type *mimetype* in the folder, I do:

```
CreateDocumentRequest.Builder builder = new CreateDocumentRequest.Builder({environmentId}, {collectionId}).file(f, mimetype);
CreateDocumentResponse createResponse = discovery.createDocument(builder.build()).execute();
```

Is it possible that the Discovery instance gets a time-out during the loop ? Should I initialize a new Discovery instance for every request ?

**UPDATE**

I am pretty sure that the exception occurs because of connectivity issues. Now I am trying to add documents such that when the connection is lost, the `Discovery` instance is reinitialized. However, it gives `INFO: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`.

```
boolean successful;
do {
    try {
        CreateDocumentResponse createResponse = this.discovery.createDocument(builder.build()).execute();
        System.out.println(createResponse.toString());
        successful = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            System.err.println("InterruptedException: " + e1.getMessage());
        }
        this.discovery = new Discovery("2017-08-01");
        this.discovery.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api");
        this.discovery.setUsernameAndPassword(DataUploader.USERNAME, DataUploader.PASSWORD);
        successful = false;
    }
} while (!successful)
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you have included, your approach seems reasonable. You don't have to create an instance of the discovery class for each request to add a document. What I think the core issue here is the handling of the file stream that you are supplying to `CreateDocumentRequest.Builder`. From what I can tell, it looks like the file stream is getting closed prematurely.

Here is a scala example that does something similar by uploading all the files in a folder which works without issues.

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.discovery.v1.Discovery
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.discovery.v1.model.document.CreateDocumentRequest
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.http.HttpMediaType

object Run {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if(args.length == 0) {
      println("Usage: <app> <folder-to-upload>")
      System.exit(0)
    }

    val discovery = new Discovery("2017-08-01")
    discovery.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api")
    discovery.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}", "{password}")

    val environmentId = "<environment-id>"
    val collectionId = "<collection-id>"

    Files.list(Paths.get(args(0))).forEach { path =>
      println(s"Processing ${path.getFileName}")
      val createDocumentBuilder = new CreateDocumentRequest.Builder(environmentId, collectionId)
        .file(path.toFile, HttpMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      val response = discovery.createDocument(createDocumentBuilder.build()).execute()
      println(s"DocumentID ${response.getDocumentId}")
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable determine which method you are using based on the provided snippet but I would use `Builder#file(File inputFile, String mediaType)` method over `Builder#file(InputStream content, String mediaType)` if given the choice. Otherwise, you have to ensure that the stream is not closed until you are sure that the request is built and sent to the server.

Comment: I am already using `Builder file(File inputFile, String mediaType)`. The error occurs in different iteration indices, so I think the issue may be due to the bandwidth of my connection.

Comment: I am unable to add a comment to your update, but you don't have to re-initialize the discovery class. If you look at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/discovery/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/discovery/v1/Discovery.java#L89, you can see that there is nothing special that happens during initialization. It only stores the information that it might need when making calls to the endpoint at a later point in time. 

You might be correct about connectivity issues. You could retry the document upload request when you get an exception.